# Call Activity from Action Bar menu item click

Tags: java, android

I have 1 Fragment and 2 activities: `HomeFragment`, `ProductActivity`, and `CartActivity`. I want to call `CartActivity` whenever I click on the cart in the menu. But when I tap on 1 product in `HomeFrament`, my app calls `ProductActivity` and `CartActivity` under `ProductActivity`.

I am using implementation `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2`.

In Product.java, I call Cart Activity in onOptionsItemSelected

```
// Click on option button.
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id){
        case android.R.id.home: {
            this.finish();
        }
        case R.id.app_bar_cart: {
            Log.d(TAG,"Cart Clicked");
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Cart.class);
            //intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.project.coconuc">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".Cart"/>
        <activity android:name=".product" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

onClick call products

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(Integer position) {
        Intent callProductActivity = new Intent(mfragment.getActivity(), product.class);
        callProductActivity.putExtra("variable", position.toString());
        Objects.requireNonNull(mfragment.getActivity()).startActivity(callProductActivity);
    }
```

For more details, please see this image: https://ibb.co/mFFZC30

This is my code:
https://github.com/KhoaChau0594/MoblileAppProject/tree/temp

Comment: Show your `Manifest` file, specifically these activitiy tags.

Comment: I have updated Manyfest file

Comment: can you show us the onClick of the products?

Comment: Is it behaves the same when you go back by Toolbar back arrow and by android back button?

Comment: And also tell are you using one activity with fragments named ProductActivity and CartActivity?

Comment: it will return to cart activity if i click toolbar back button. if I click the back button of the phone it will return to Home Fragment

Comment: I have update my code

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem.
It caused because the implement of the toolbar back button in the product activity. I have to use getSupportActionBar() instead of getActionBar().

This is how i implement back button

```
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```